# Adding tag after switching view controllers

Tags: ios, tags, segue, viewcontroller

I have a randomly generated int that I assign to a tag for a UIImageView on my storyboard in ViewWillAppear.

When I segue to the main menu and try to enter the view again, however, the app crashes. I know it's because of the tag because when I remove it everything works fine.

Any thoughts on why it works the first time but not on times after that? Code below.

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    int tagnumber;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *box;
    ...
}
```

ViewController.m:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    tagnumber = arc4random()%1000;
    box.tag = tagnumber;
    ...
}

- (IBAction)unwindToThisViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
{
    [_animator removeAllBehaviors];
    [box removeFromSuperview];
}
```

MainMenu.m:

```
-(IBAction)prepareForUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
}
```

Comment: Try removing `[box removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It's worth noting that I'm using a UIdynamics animator with gravity on the box, and the error message that I'm getting the second time I use it is that the box is no longer a descendant of the view. It works fine the first time, however.

Comment: My response is too long for a comment so i'll put it under an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, when the view disappears and the system is running out of memory, it will call on UIViewController's implementation of `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.  There is a fantastic description of this here: [ViewWillDisappear versus dealloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788864/viewwilldisappear-versus-dealloc)

When you are creating an IBOutput you should really have a weak pointer to it by saying `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *box`.  Views retain their subviews, and therefore, if a view gets deallocated, its subviews retain count decreases by one. When the view disappears, the system will decide when to deallocate self.view, and when it does, it will automatically release box, and box will get deallocated as well. You don't really need to worry about it.

Comment: Ahh this is so, so helpful. Thank you so much!! I have a feeling that this will solve my problem, but I have one last question-- where should I add that property line of code? When I add it in .h it gives error "illegal visibility specification". When I add it in .m after interface, every line that references box has an error "Member reference base type 'int (WINDOW*, chtype, chtype)' is not a structure or union...

Comment: Nevermind! I added it underneath the close bracket of interface in .h and all the errors went away. I got another error message upon compiling and going to the view controller saying that it attempted to insert nil objects from objects[0], but I'll see if I can tackle that issue separately. Thank you so much!!